# How to read only the visible rows from an xls/xlsx file

Tags: python-2.7, xlsx, xlrd, import-from-excel, autofilter

I am reading a large number of Excel files, each applied with a different autofilter. Therefore, sometimes out of say 1000 rows, only five are visible and that is what I want to read in my Python script using the xlrd module. Instead, the script ends up reading in all 1000 rows which I do not want.

I tried the "formatting_info" tag which didn't work.

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(sheet, formatting_info = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

formatting_info only trims the right and bottom of the sheet.

have you tried:

rowinfo() hidden?

You would have to foreach through each row, but it should speed things up a little bit?

Comment: It seems that rowinfo.hidden has been dropped in recent versions of the xlrd ( 0.9.4/5 ). I have tried using it, which keeps yielding syntax errors.

Comment: I see there is a rowInfo class implemented, but I have been trying and I am not quite sure how to use it correctly to see whether a certain row was hidden by an autofilter.